# How can I remove time range in scatter plot?

Tags: palantir-foundry

I’ve added a time range to a Scatter Plot in Quiver, however I can’t seem to delete it. How does it work ? And how am I supposed to remove components from one another ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your problem, I take it that you are not able to delete a widget you’ve added that’s linked to another one.

If you delete a dataset that a chart is using, the chart will be deleted too. To understand what’s going on, you need to know how your dependencies are working in Quiver.

To see it better, you can click on the Canvas view and switch to Graph :
[image: Top right corner of quiver]

In this view, you’ll able to visualize how all the widgets and datasets you’re using are connected between each other, making it easier to know which dataset is used to display what chart. This is especially useful in your case where some widgets aren’t in the Canvas, so they’re not visible but still used.

So if you want to remove your time range, check the dependencies of your Quiver App, click on the three dots next to the widget and click on “Delete”. Beware that removing a parent widget will remove all the widgets that depend on it.
[image: Delete button]